# Mixture Noise on Image with Matlab

Tags: matlab, noise

With some requirement it needs to add mixture noise to image in Matlab. Mixture will have Salt & Pepper Noise varying from 5% to 23% with the fix 5% of Gaussian Noise. I am trying to add said mixture to Image with following code:

```
I = imread('lena_gray_512.tif');
figure, imshow(I);title('ORIGINAL');

J = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper', 0.23);
figure, imshow(J);title('salty');

K = imnoise(J,'gaussian',0,0.0005);
figure, imshow(K);title('both');
```

First thing is to verify whether the code will add said required noise to image of 23% Salt& Peeper and 5% Gaussian Noise?

Further, median filter is used to remove the mixed Noise from Image, it works good having PSNR 35. Is there any way to get PSNR around 50 for the same Image with this same mixed Noise?

Comment: Gaussian Noise had two parameters, mean and variance. If i had told to add 10% Gaussian Noise then which parameter will have what value?

Comment: I am beginner to Matlab. It will surely easy for you but for me its big task. Whether the above code will add 10% Gaussian noise or not? Could you kindly provide the wiener filter code here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Measuring noise in `[%]` is very unclear. I suggest you go to the source (book / article / slideshow) you saw the value in, and see how it is defined there. Then come back and tell us...